# What is this exercise/pose called?

Tags: yoga, gymnastics

Standing on one foot, other foot above the head, back arched, hands reach over the head, grasping the foot. So legs are in a 'splits' position.

I wanna look into how to progress into such a position, but I need the name first. I see cheerleaders on Instagram doing it all the time, if they can do it... lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a variation of [dancer's pose (Natarajasana)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natarajasana):

[image]

that is often called [king dancer's pose](http://yoga.about.com/od/yogaposes/a/kingdancer.htm).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Because you mentioned cheerleaders and the splits position: I think what you mean is [the needle pose](http://www.ehow.com/how_6716739_stretch-needle-cheerleading.html). The link leads to a wikihow article on how to train for it. They mostly mention how important it is to warm up properly. Both your legs and back need to be warm and stretched. In the linked article they say to practice this move by performing you splits on the floor and laying back, try to get your head all the way down to your leg. Practicing against a wall before you try it freestanding also helps.

[image: Girl performing needle pose]